# Page numbering in PhD thesis

Tags: page-layout, numbering

I have always wondered: where should the first page number start?  I know the front matter is typically in lower case roman numbers, whereas the mainmatter is with arabic ones.

The mainmatter starts the count ---i.e., page 1--- with Chapter 1; but I have no idea where the frontmatter should begging the counter.

For example, in a PhD thesis typically there is a page with the title, a quote, an abstract, a dedicatory, table of contents, list of figures, list of tables, list of acronyms.

So, two questions:

1) What should be the order of things for the frontmatter

2) What should be numbered in the front matter, and what shouldn't count as part of it?

Comment: belongs at http://academia.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 8):

In the US, the standard manual for all of this is [*The Chicago Manual of Style*](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/home.html), published by the University of Chicago Press. It defines the order of front matter, back matter, the things that are necessary and those that are optional.

The front matter begins with the first page inside the cover. In a book, that is the "half title" page. An epigraph or a table of contents generally appears on page v (unless there is a dedication, which has first choice for v).

*Chicago* specifies:

> i - half title
>
> ii - Series title, frontispiece, or blank
>
> iii - Title page
>
> iv - Copyright page
>
> v - Dedication
>
> v or vi - Epigraph
>
> v or vii - Table of Contents
>
> List of Illustrations, can be on a right (recto) or left (verso) page.
>
> List of Tables, ditto.
>
> Foreword (always a recto)
>
> Preface (recto)
>
> Acknowledgements, if not already in the preface. (recto)
>
> Introduction (unless part of the main text) (recto)
>
> Abbreviations (unless in the back matter) (recto or verso)
>
> Chronology (unless in the back matter) (recto)
>
> Second half title, if included (recto)

Not all of these would apply to a thesis, of course. I suggest a trip to the library to spend a convivial hour or two with *Chicago* or a local equivalent for other countries. It's unlikely that any questions you have in this realm are not answered in those pages.

A possibly more pragmatic approach would be to look at some previously published theses from your institution and use one of those as a model.

Comment: There are a few slightly different ways of doing it, and as long as your university does not follow a given standard, you can use the one that makes most sense. What is the most important thing is to be consistent in page numbering, appendices, references, addendums etc.

Comment: An excellent point. I took a guess that Mario wasn't speaking specifically of a university publication, since he prefaces the third paragraph with "For example".

Comment: Actually it is for a PhD thesis... but there is no mandatory template, so the natural "do what they tell you to do" answer is not useful.  What do you feel about the order?

Comment: @boblet What do you feel is the prefer order?

Comment: Thanks @Alan, and of course, it was an example he used. Having read more essays and mini-theses than I care to count, I would say that the absolutely most important thing is consistency. And if you are going to get a little creative, then make it visually ludicrously easy to navigate (so as not to annoy your professor/reader/subject). By that I mean a consistency throughout the document. If there is no pagination somewhere, you cannot reference it, and neither can other people. Make it easy for people to read, to navigate, and in academia: very important: make it citeable!

Comment: ah, what i prefer? I think I might write an answer instead of doing a lecture here in the comment field! :D I would like to say, thought, that @AlanGilbertson point is very very valid. Standing on the shoulders of giants and all that. If it was good enough for Einstein..

Answer (score 3):

First, I would second @AlanGilbertson in go and have a look at Chicago. These thesis templates might seem dusty and a tad boring, but there are some good arguments for them:

1. International standards. Should your thesis ever be of interest other places, a standard might be useful.
2. It will save you time in the long run, as soon as you have your document setup. Though that can be fiddly.
3. These standards might have taken into account things you have not thought about yet. Nothing is more annoying than after 123 pages realising that you have to go through every page to do something tedious because you did not think of it.

### Flexibility

Whatever solution you come up with, you should make absolutely sure that your document is as flexible as possible. With some luck your eminent thesis might be the basis for articles, presentations, keynotes etc; so do not use archaic software or bizarre or uncommon fonts. Most journals will ask you to provide text according to their standards, so do not lock your document into something that would be a hassle to reformat down the line.

### Readability, simplicity

The absolute most important thing is to make sure it is as easy and comfortable to read as possible. This to ensure that you do not annoy the readers. You want to make it as smooth for the sensors as possible, and you want them to focus on the content, not be annoyed at the packaging. For you to shine in a thesis, you will have to do it through words and media (images, video, graphs, diagrams, audio...), not through creative expression in layout. You must make navigation and referencing as simple as possible.

Of course, there is the possibility that your thesis breaks the boundaries of a standard thesis, and then that needs to be considered too, but the standards will contain pretty much everything. If your thesis is - for example - heavily dependant on links to web, software, prototypes, consider making your own way of highlighting these important links. Do not  let these essential bits drown, just because the Chicago style have not accounted for it.

**Pagination**

In academia, remember: no one can – or will! – reference something that does not have a page number. If there is content you or others need to refer to; it must have at the very least a page number of some sort.

**University standard page**

Your university may not have a standard for the whole shebang, but most will have a "required-box" or even a page of some sort, with uni name, thesis title, copyrights, contact info, dates, advisors, stakeholders and keywords. Where to put this is a hassle. I say get it over with as soon as possible.

**Personal opinion..**

So, to my personal opinion. This depends on how complex your thesis will be, but I belong to the "keep it as simple as possible but not one bit simpler".

I partly follow the Chicago model, but I move content around a little, and I simplify a great deal. I go with roman numerals all the way to the *end* of the table of content. I also add in white pages to make sure it works well when printed. Do not be afraid of empty left pages. Use them when sensible.

Personally, I would stick ALL lists of illustrations, tables etc in an appendix. I see no reason why the reader should plough through lots of lists of stuff s/he has not even seen. Use Image captions, image numbers for reference in appendix.

Here is a basic layout of what I prefer:
[image]

[image]

### General hints:

- Spend some time formatting the table of contents so that it looks
  good and are immediately easy to navigate.
- 1.5 line-space, font, Times, Times New Roman or very similar.
- Headings: here you have more freedom, but make them clear, simple,
  readable with good indents and size differences.
- Make a footer with name of thesis and your name. Make it *subtle*.
  Light gray is good.
- Use appendices
- Use sensible referencing, such as Chicago or Harvard (stay away from the stupid IT-idea of numbers in brackets).
- Make sure your footnotes are well made: they are not AS important as
  the main content, you can tone then down a little so not to interfere
  with the main stuff.

Comment: Great answer! Now the fine details: where would you put the initial quote, the list of publications and the acknowledgements?

Comment: Not sure if I understand you - initial quote; is that the abstract (three-four sentences "pitch")? list of publication, do you mean the references? Acknowledgements I would either put as the first appendix; or in special circumstances, before the table of content. However, I think I personally would combine dedication and acknowledgements Authors often do this. I believe in less clutter in the beginning, information for the specially interested in the back. Sensible use of footnotes. List of abbreviations I would also put in an appendix, but clearly refer to its existence when appropriate.

Comment: Abstract is the small resume of the whole work.  The publications are all the articles that were published while you were working on your thesis and acknowledgements are the people you want to thank: lab technicians, special places, organizations, etc; wheras the dedicatory is a small sentence like "to my wife"

Comment: Are you sure about a running footer for author and title? I don't think I've ever seen a book that has included that as a footer, rather than a header. Also, I would advise against 1.5x spacing: again, every book you read that is text with a few pictures and diagrams has the text single spaced: a thesis is such a book. (Note, though, that many universities have strict requirements about spacing. For example, my own thesis is double-spaced, single-sided because, er, the university library wants to store in perpetuity four times as much paper as is needed, or something?)

Comment: If also delivered and stored digitally, I would have a footer: sensor/people prints it out, footer is useful because he ends up with piles of paper, and likely has more than one thesis to read. The 1.5 line height though, is a good thing. Sensors read massive stacks, and it _is_ easier to read. I thought it silly until I had to read hundreds of essays. 1.5 is pretty much an academic standard. I would simply not deviate from the this in something that obvious, and risk annoying a traditional-minded sensor. It is also easier to take notes, both for you working on it, and for the sensors.

Comment: actually, I could go with a header instead of a footer, but then I would have the pagination also on the header.

Comment: @MarioS.E. I believe in  keeping the pages up to the actual thesis as simple as possible. Articles and book published that you have read but do not have any _direct reference to_, goes in appendix "bibliography". If possible I would combine "to my wife" with "thanks to lab-Bob". Authors do this all the time. If the thank-you list is massive, I would stick it in the back. Or after "to my wife". I flick through first pages. I read the abstract. I skim the table of content. Read the thesis. Skim the appendices. Check references. As a sensor, the rest I usually ignore.

Comment: @boblet "1.5 is pretty much an academic standard." That must be field-dependent. My experience (mathematics, computer science, some physical sciences) includes exactly one paper that has been typeset at something other than single line spacing. Books are single-spaced, papers are single-spaced, tech reports are single-spaced.

Comment: @DavidRicherby interesting. I suppose it could also be a geographic thing. In my experience from Scandinavia, Australia and D.C., following the Harvard style might be prevalent. Chicago, I think, say 2, which seems excessive to me. But by all means, do whatever you like as long as your uni does not impose anything specific. I am merely speaking from experience.

Comment: Oh, and btw, as mentioned above, IT-fields tend to do their own thing for some reason. They often do the reference number in brackets which to me is extremely inefficient and clumsy to read.

Comment: @boblet We usually use 1.5 half spacing because most of the supervisors are... well, old.  Regarding the citation style, in biomedical engineering we also usually go with author-date style. `IEEEtranSN` is perfect for this while using `LaTeX`.

Comment: Oh, and regarding the publications... I meant the publications you *wrote* while doing your thesis, i.e., the papers that you published as an author.  Something like the "Also from the author" in books.

Comment: Haha - LaTEx :D good for you. Hate the thing. I see, other stuff you wrote simultaneously; I would definitely stick that in the front.